# Plop boot menu in ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, xubuntu

I have an old sony laptop that doesn't support booting from USB and its CD ROM drive is broken.  Previously I was able to boot from USB through plop boot manager, but recently I deleted partitions and installed Zorin OS to try it.

Now I wanted to install Xubuntu, but I could not boot from USB since plop boot manager is no longer available given that the MBR was over written by Zorin. I tried intalling plop boot menu from Zorin, but I wasn't able to.

I tried different entries but I get error messages like

```
unknown file system/ partition not found!
```

I am able to run Zorin normally.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a way to fix the problem. I used [this guide](http://makegadgetswork.blogspot.com/2012/02/how-to-boot-from-usb-when-bios-does-not.html)

Download Plop boot manager from [here](https://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager/download.html) - use `plpbt-5.0.14.zip`

Assuming it was saved to your Downloads directory, unzip it and copy two files to `/boot`:

```
cd ~/Downloads
unzip plpbt-5.0.14.zip
sudo cp plpbt-5.0.14/Linux/plpbt.bin /boot
sudo cp plpbt-5.0.14/Linux/plpcfgbt /boot
```

Now you need to edit the file `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`, but you need some of the contents of the file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` so open it with your favourite text editor and use it to find something similar to these lines (starting with insmod ext2 and ending with something close to the output of `cat proc/cmdline`). There may be several entries that are similar (one for each installed kernel):

```
 insmod ext2
 if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  4ee1bbce-9d64-44b6-821b-511e06a804e0
 else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 4ee1bbce-9d64-44b6-821b-511e06a804e0
 fi
 linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-27-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=4ee1bbce-9d64-44b6-821b-511e06a804e0 ro  resume=/dev/mmcblk1p3 initcall_debug no_console_suspend intel_idle.max_cstate=1
```

Copy those lines, and then open `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` with your favourite text editor, for example

```
 sudo nano /etc/grub.d/40_custom
```

And add at the end of the file

```
menuentry "Plop Bootmanager" {
```

Then paste the lines from `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` **but** change the last one and add a closing `}` so finally the whole file is something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
menuentry "Plop Bootmanager" {
insmod ext2
 if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  4ee1bbce-9d64-44b6-821b-511e06a804e0
 else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 4ee1bbce-9d64-44b6-821b-511e06a804e0
 fi
 linux16 /boot/plpbt.bin
}
```

Note: if there is a line starting with `set root` instead of the `if/else` statements then leave that line, but if there is a line starting with `echo`, remove it

**Make sure you leave at least 2 newlines at the end of the file.**

Save, exit, and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

And Plop Bootmanager will be added to your GRUB menu.